# How to align/move a DefaultTabController to be side by side in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to align/move a DefaultTabController to be side by side in Flutter? [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve3Qj.png). When I try to do this, the widget deploys in the center

Comment: You should refere https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as an option:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Home'),
            bottom: TabBarWrapper(
              tabBar: TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(child: Text('Programs')),
                  Tab(child: Text('Bookings')),
                ],
              ),
              child: RightSideWidget(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TabBarWrapper extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final PreferredSizeWidget tabBar;
  final Widget child;

  const TabBarWrapper({required this.tabBar, required this.child, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        IntrinsicWidth(child: tabBar),
        Expanded(child: child),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => tabBar.preferredSize;
}

class RightSideWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const RightSideWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Icon(Icons.qr_code, color: Colors.white, size: 20),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 16),
          child: Text(('Scan'), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]